# Unable to set PHP $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, session, cookies

The Problem: Despite starting the session and declaring variables, the variables aren't actually set, and are not callable on other pages.

Using the Web inspector, I can see that the PHPSESSID cookie is set, and is the same on the second page I tried to call the variables from. But there are no variables.

The code:

../test1.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$session_name = 'trialAndError';   // Set a custom session name

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";

?>
```

Then I try to call the variable on this next page...and I get nothing...

../test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_name = 'trialAndError';   // Set a custom session name

// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . "<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"];
?>
```

When I load ../test2.php the page displays:

Favorite color is 
Favorite animal is

When I check the web inspector, I cannot see the session variables.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You wouldn't normally see the session vars, only the session cookie, which is usually called PHPSESSID -- can you see that?

Comment: yes I see that. and PHPSESSID matches from ../test1.php and ../test2.php. But if the session variables were set, then the output from ../test2.php should read Favorite color is green   Favorite animal is cat.

Comment: How do you go from ./test1.php to ./test2.php?

Comment: I just type it in the URL. If you'd like to see the actual page: http://www.impossibleparty.com/private/test2.php and http://www.impossibleparty.com/private/test1.php

Comment: run `phpinfo();` and edit your question adding what you see under **session**

Comment: odd: `var_dump($_SESSIONS)` on page 2

Comment: results from phpinfo() Session section: session support-enabled. registered save handlers-files user split. registered serializer handlers-php php_binary cddx

Comment: full error checking and display on:  at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: var_dump($_SESSIONS) displayed NULL. I changed it to var_dump($_SESSION) because i thought that might be a typo... and I got array(0) {}

Comment: okkk see the errors now - session file not writing i assme this is hosted by someone- you need to contact their support, you can set you own session path if you prefer, but suggest the host fixes it

Comment: @Dagon: I adjusted the code to add your code just under session_start();

`<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);
$session_name = 'trialAndError';   // Set a custom session name

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
?>`

The results on next comment

Comment: And now you see what the problem is: "Warning: Unknown: open(/var/php_sessions/sess_7452199232ec343293deeea2def427b1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct(/var/php_sessions) in Unknown on line 0 "

Comment: I don't understand what that means. How do I fix it?

Comment: contact the host is the easiest\best option

Comment: So I know what I'm talking about when I call them. It is something to do with a php configuration that doesn't allow sessions?

Comment: "Hi, i cant create sessions on my site because the session path directory either does not exist or is not writable"

Comment: @Dagon: Do you want to write that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your host has failed to set up the server correctly so that you cant write session files. While you can set your own session path, its a probably a batter idea to get the host to fix it's configuration.

To set your own path you use  [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) , from that page:

> session.save_path string session.save_path defines the argument which
>   is passed to the save handler. If you choose the default files
>   handler, this is the path where the files are created. See also
>   session_save_path(). ...

Comment: Just had a chat with iPage who hosts my site. They said php.ini was never activated and that was an error on their part. Hours later, the problem is resolved and ../test2.php now reads the proper variables. Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: yup, that is something you pay them for ;-)

Comment: just remember how much useful info you got when you had error reporting on, should always develop that way